# Как написать слово "Лаго(-)Наки"?

Tags: орфография, слитно-дефис

Как правильно пишется слово **Лаго-Наки**?
Пишут это слово и слитно — Лагонаки, и через дефис.

Answer (score 2):

Я посмотрел поиском в сети несколько источников и попытался оценить их авторитетность. В тех источниках, которые я счёл более авторитетными, используется слитное написание. Например: (а) [в этом словаре](http://docplayer.ru/53328750-Slovar-geograficheskih-nazvaniy-krasnodarskogo-kraya.html) и (б) в работе доктора филологических  наук В.Г. Борботько "К разгадке топонима «Лагонаки»".

Не исключаю, что написание через дефис также допустимо, но если это не удастся выяснить наверняка, надёжнее использовать слитное написание, я думаю.